# How can I divide a List into tokens by comma

Tags: python

Hi i am really new to python. I would like to ask whether based on my code below, how can I actually divide the list, inst, into tokens by comma

```
print("ID - actual - predicted")
for index, inst in enumerate(test):
    print "\n", inst
    pred = cls.classify_instance(inst)
    dist = cls.distribution_for_instance(inst)
    print(
        "%d - %s - %s" %
        (index+1, inst.get_string_value(inst.class_index)
         ,inst.class_attribute.value(int(pred))))
split_inst = inst.split(",")
```

So what I try to do is splitting it by comma. But I keep on getting error like 'Instance' object has no attribute 'split' like this:

```
22,in,in,1,PP,21,prep,IN,pr,null,null,null,null,null,null,the,DT,det,def,null,null,sg,null,null,system,NN,null,null,null,in,IN,recorded,VBN,NN,?
95 - ? - nonerror

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python FYP\Tkinter\prediction.py", line 44, in <module>
  main(sys.argv)
 File "C:\Python FYP\Tkinter\prediction.py", line 38, in main
 split_inst = inst.split(',')
AttributeError: 'Instance' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Is that a string?

Comment: I think the variable, inst is a list. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Sagar I am sorry.. yeah its a list of  strings

Comment: Don't paste images of traceback, put it in your code as code snippet.

Comment: You are trying to access `inst` variable outside of your for-loop where you declare it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your question, you are using object for split function.
so  copy the object string into different variable and then try to split it.

Because objects can not splitted, it has to be string